# Redirecting site to sub-sub folder

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a website in my `public_html` folder placed in the following folder structure

```
public_html/dps/main
```

I am using .htaccess to redirect in the following format ;

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.co.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dps/main/
RewriteCond /domain/%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dps/main/$1/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.co.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dps/main/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dps/main/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /dps/main/index.php [L]
```

Unfortunately it gives me Internal Server Error

not sure what is wrong with this code.

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your rules with this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!dps/main/).*)$ /dps/main/$1 [L,NC]
```